# Integral over $2D$ surface in $3D$

Tags: surface-integrals

The projection of the element of two-dimensional surfaces in three dimensions on coordinate planes $x_\alpha x_\beta$ is an antisymmetric tensor of rank $2$

$$df_{\alpha\beta}=dx_{\alpha} dx_{\beta}'-dx_{\beta} dx'_{\alpha}$$

It is said in a textbook that as an element of integration over the two-dimensional surfaces in three dimensions is taken the dual of $df_{\alpha\beta}$

$$\ast df_{\alpha\beta}=\frac{1}{2}\varepsilon_{\alpha}\small^{\beta\gamma}df_{\beta\gamma}$$

How to understand intuitively the reason for switching from the projection to its dual?

Comment: This is the same identification we have with planes and normal vectors.

Comment: Can you explain broadly?

Comment: A plane requires a point and a normal vector. But let's say we were integrating over this plane. A translation in space does not affect it's differential element (differential form), so the only identifier it has left is its orientation. An area element also needs a size associated with it - in other words a magnitude and orientation, which can be encoded by another differential form.